# angularjs how to post key/values not json object

Tags: angularjs, post

I hava a json object in my ctl:

```
$scope.disease
```

and anyone can edit it's properties and then post to server.

when save it,

```
$scope.save = function(){
    $http.post('/***', $scope.disease)
}
```

however, the request body is as a json string.
while I want it to be as form data:

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
key3: value3
```

how can I do?

thanks a lot

---

after I set the Content-Type like this:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
}])
```

the request header:

```
Accept  application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding     gzip, deflate
Accept-Language     en-US,en;q=0.5
Content-Type   application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
```

however the post parameter like this:

```
{"age":56,"birthday":"1958-07-14","familyHistory":"********************","id":1,"illness":"*********************","illnessHistory":"***************************","number":"21","selfDescription":"***********************"}
```

Because the $scope.disease is:

```
{
    "age": 56,
    "birthday": "1958-07-14",
    "familyHistory": "********************",
    "id": 1,
    "illness": "*********************",
    "illnessHistory": "***************************",
    "number": "21",
    "selfDescription": "***********************"
}
```

while the post parameter should like this:

```
"age": 56,
"birthday": "1958-07-14",
"familyHistory": "********************",
"id": 1,
"illness": "*********************",
"illnessHistory": "***************************",
"number": "21",
"selfDescription": "***********************"
```

Do you understand me?

Finally I add a transformRequest method to post-request:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest=function(obj){
var str =[];
for(var p in obj){
str.push(encodeURICompent(p)+'='+encodeURICompent(obj[p]));
}
return str.join('&');
}
```

Then the problem solved!

Comment: Oh, my absolutely require though I can parse it at my server-side, I don't think I should parse it at server-side

Comment: My server-side is Java with Spring restful

Comment: If this can't be resolved,I will try to fetch keys from $scope.disease manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `$http.post` call, add a correct Content-Type header to the `config` object (third parameter). If left empty, Angular defaults to a JSON payload.

```
headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Content-Type` attribute of the header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` using the $[httpProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider) on your config or do it for each request on the $http service.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in below mentioned ways

```
     this.createOrder = function(userId,accountId,deliveryDate,cutOffDateTime,customerRef){       
          var orderCreateURL = contextProp.baseURL + '/users/'+userId+'/account/orders';       
          return $http({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: orderCreateURL,
                  data:{
                      'accountId': accountId,
                      'deliveryDate':deliveryDate,
                      'cutOffDateTime':cutOffDateTime,
                      'customerRef':customerRef
                   }
         });
    };
```

It will post your data in key,value pairs. You can also specify the headers i.e. headers: {'Content-Type': undefined } and transformRequest: angular.identity etc.. in parameters same as any other HTTP requests. Thanks.